# How can I set textView in Fragment From Activity at on create method

Tags: android

How can I change text in text view in fragment from activity?

I want one activity that's name is `mainActivity`  and two `fragment` that name are `Homefragment` and `cityFragment`.

In home Fragment I have a `TextView` That its id is txt1.

I want `settext` this text view in `onCreate` method in main activity.

Right now I'm trying this code but this give me error.

```
TextView tv=(TextView) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.homeFr).
    getView().findViewById(R.id.txt_1);
    tv.setText("hi");
```

Comment: Have you initialised the Fragment by the time you call it in `onCreate()`? If you could link the full error here that would help

Comment: Include full code with proper details